# Make grunt bower get minified version from "bower_components"

Tags: gruntjs, bower

In my `GruntFile.js` I have `bower` task:

```
bower: {
    dev: {
        dest: 'lib'// will get stuff from 'bower_components' to 'lib' folder
    }
},
```

So when I do: `grunt bower` it transforms **some** stuff from `bower_component` folder to `lib`.. so I end up having files like: `angular.js` in the /`lib`.

But it does not copy `"angular.min.js"`, which sits in `bower_component`.

**Q:** How can I configure grunt bower task to copy minified v of files too?

I do not want to put minify/uglify tasks to GruntFile just yet. Since those files are already minified in `bower_components`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the bower task just to download bower components and add a copy task to move files around as needed.

Install grunt-contrib-copy

```
npm install grunt-contrib-copy --save-dev
```

And use it in your grunt file:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),  
    /* more tasks... */
    copy: {
      main: {
        files: [
          // includes files within path
          {expand: true, src: ['path/*'], dest: 'dest/', filter: 'isFile'},

          // includes files within path and its sub-directories
          {expand: true, src: ['path/**'], dest: 'dest/'},

          // makes all src relative to cwd
          {expand: true, cwd: 'path/', src: ['**'], dest: 'dest/'},

          // flattens results to a single level
          {expand: true, flatten: true, src: ['path/**'], dest: 'dest/', filter: 'isFile'},
        ],
      },
    }
});
```

You can configure it to copy just what the `**.min.js` files.

Comment: Is it that you are using ``bower-components/**/*.min.js`` instead of ``bower_components/**/*.min.js`` the problem ?